# What kind of dash is used before a quote attribution?

Tags: punctuation, typography, quoting

In this quote example:

“Planning your video is the first step.”
-Christine Cloud, Producer

Should the name be preceded by an em dash, or a swung dash?

Answer (score 8):

A look inside [`manmac.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/base/manmac.tex),  which is some macros for The famous TeXbook, reveals the definition of `\author`:

```
\def\author#1(#2){\smallskip\noindent\rm--- #1\unskip\enspace(#2)}
```

which uses `---` (EM-Dash) for quotes.

Comment: Very interesting information! I didn't know that at all.

Answer (score 5):

I shouldn't use swung dash (~) at all.

According to [grammarbook.com](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/dashes.asp), the Em Dash should be preferable for a more informal writing in English language. The Em Dash is used (among other cases) to separate phrases.

In any case, I'd rather use:

> “Planning your video is the first step.” Christine Cloud, Producer

but this could also be chosen:

> “Planning your video is the first step.” —Christine Cloud, Producer

Comment: Thank you, looks good. If they want to break it onto two lines, is it okay to start a line with the em dash?